# Pass Choice Parameter to Another Job in Jenkins with DSL Build Flow

Tags: jenkins, parameters, branch, git-branch, jenkins-build-flow

I'm using the Build Flow plugin to perform parallel builds.  I need to pass a choice parameter (branch_name) from the parent job to the child jobs.  I'm unsure how to get this working.  The choice parameter has multiple branch names.  How can I do this?

Here's an sample of the code,

```
// Here's where I set the variable for the choice parameter (branch_name)

branch_name = ${branch_name}

// Here's where I call the variable to pass to the other jobs

 parallel (
  { build("build1", branch_name:params["branch_name"], },
  { build("build2", branch_name:params["branch_name"], },
  { build("build3", branch_name:params["branch_name"], },
  { build("build4", branch_name:params["branch_name"], },
)
```

What am I doing wrong?  Please help.  Thx.

Answer (score 3):

Assume you got this working? For future Googlers, I believe it would be as follows:

```
// Get the parameter of the parent, flow job - should be available as environment variable
def branch = build.environment.get("PARENT_PARAM_NAME")

parallel (
    // pass to child job
    { build("build1", CHILD_PARAM_NAME: branch)},
    // repeat as required
)
```